# wait for user to click the notification in react-native-fcm

Tags: react-native

**Im using react-native-fcm for push notification. Its redirects to no another component when the notification comes. It doesnt wait for the user to click.**

```
FCM.on("FCMNotificationReceived", (notif) => {
  console.log("Notification", notif);
  if(notif.click_action === "ACTION"){
    Actions.login()
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

While creating a local notification you need to add auto_cancel as false. (default is true)

```
FCM.presentLocalNotification({
            id: "UNIQ_ID_STRING",        
            title: "My Notification Title",   
            body: "My Notification Message",   
            sound: "default",    
            priority: "high",       
            click_action: "ACTION",       
            auto_cancel: false,          
            large_icon: "ic_launcher",         
            icon: "ic_launcher",                            
            big_text: "Show when notification is expanded", 
            sub_text: "This is a subText",           
            vibrate: 300,              
            wake_screen: true,      
            group: "group",
            picture: "https://google.png",
            show_in_foreground
        });
```